# Netgear DGND4000 ADSL configuration and slow connection

Tags: networking, router, internet, adsl

I live in Italy and I recently bought a DGND4000 Modem/Router from Netgear.

I have configured the "Internet Setup" and the "ADSL settings" pages with the data given to me by the ISP.

As ISP I use "Infostrada" and I should a have 8 Mbps bandwidth, but my problem is that when I check the connection with services like speedtest.net it reaches only 2.5 or less even thought in the statistics the downstream is 8127 Kbps.

So my questions are:

1. Could there be a bottleneck from the computer?
2. Is there a best configuration for the modem part of this device?

Here is a screenshot of the device statistics:

[image]
Also I have talked with technicians of my ISP and they said everything is OK because the downstream is 8Mbps as the contract says.

Comment: Are you testing the speed using a wired or a wireless connection?

Comment: I've tried both ways, but the results are the same

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the full output from `Admin` -> `Router Status` -> `Show Statistics`? A link to a screenshot is OK if you can't otherwise copy the information.

Comment: You could also trying talking to your ISP.

Comment: And check pingtest.net to check for packet loss. Also pathping to a well known site, eg `bbc.co.uk`

Comment: Do you know how far you are from your telephone exchange?

Comment: Was your speedtest.net test done with no other programs (torrent for example) running?

Comment: I don't know how far I am from the telephone exchange.

Comment: Also my speedtest.net tests were done just with the browser open.